# Change in entropy of ideal gas under free expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

If a gas expands freely in an isolated container, the entropy increases because the system has transitioned to a new macrostate with more microstates available and therefore by Boltzmann's interpretation: ΔS > 0. However, since the process is adiabatic, Q/T = 0 which implies that ΔS = 0. What am I missing?

Comment: $\int \delta Q/T$ being the change in entropy only holds for a reversible process, but free expansion is not reversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is that a change in entropy due to entropy generation (as opposed to entropy transfer) doesn't require heat transfer. The equation

$$\Delta S_{12}=\int_1^2\frac{\delta q_{rev}}{T}$$

can be applied to an irreversible adiabatic process (which the free adiabatic expansion is) by assuming any convenient reversible path connecting the original and final equilibrium states that need not bear any resemblance to the actual process. We can do this because entropy is a state property that does not depend on the path between equilibrium states.

In the case of an ideal gas free adiabatic expansion, one typically assumes a reversible isothermal path between the initial and final states to determine  the entropy generated.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The real formula for entropy change is:

$$dS= \frac {\delta Q} T + \delta S_{irr}  $$

where the second term captures changes due to irreversible processes – mixing, free expansion, friction, vorticity generation in a fluid, etc.

It's somewhat analogous to how energy can be transferred recoverably by falling to a lower position in a gravity well, or unrecoverably by friction.